# React native app does not show images from google storage

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have two images. One is in the google storage and other is a random open image url
I have put them in exactly same code but react native app does not read the image from the google storage.
I have double checked, the bucket is public. And the image is loading on the webpage with the same url. It somehow does not work in the react native app

```html
<TouchableHighlight onPress = {this.handleClick.bind(null,image)}>
    <Image
     style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
     source={{ uri: "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png" }}
                     />
 </TouchableHighlight>
 <TouchableHighlight onPress = {this.handleClick.bind(null,image)}>
   <Image
   style={styles.iconImage}
   source={{ uri: "https://storage.cloud.google.com/s-uploads/org-10/1543344469Screen-Shot-2018-10-25-at-2.03.44-PM.png" }}/>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Google cloud may have permission has to change otherwise we have to provide access permissions while requesting.

Comment: I looked into it. And through lot of trial and error, I figured out it 307 redirect. So what I did was hit the url and then get the redirect url. but the redirect url is also not the desired one. I have looked all over the internet regarding the articles but had no luck.